# How to Display a form with the same name selected in the subitem of listviewitem

Tags: c#, winforms, listviewitem

I want to open a form with the same name selected in the subitem of listviewitem

example - if i select Buy in the list view check this link

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKMKF.jpg

I want to open a form with the same name called Buy check this link

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMX1K.jpg

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You could use Activator.CreateInstance().  A simple switch statement is best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find list views selected item by : SelectedItems property, Also you can get related text from subitems of listview, at last you can create a form and name it's text as selected text, sth like bellow code, just should add some checking for null selected items list.

```
var txt = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
var form = new Form();
form.Text = txt;
form.ShowDialog();
```